# Adding margins to display: table-cell child element

Tags: css, html, css-tables

I've been attempting to build a navigation using `display: table`. The code is a simple `div` as `display: table`, a `ul` for the `display: table-row` and each `li` as `display: table-cell`.

Each `li` has an `a` tag inside and I simply want to add a margin to `a` tag for the active page in the navigation defined by an `.active` class, however it seems to add the margin for every `li`.

Any idea what is going on here?

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gxpb3/4/

**Code**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Pie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pie</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Pie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pie</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

div {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    display: table-row;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    background: black;
}

li.active a {
    margin-top: 5px; 
}

a:hover {
    background: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've figured it out. Strangely, all the `li` elements increase in size when margin is added to one of the `a` tags. Adding `vertical-align` with any value seems to prevent them expanding and produces the desired effect.

However, I have no idea why this happens.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2DGjV/